# How to pad with leading zeros without changing the last 0?

Tags: regular-expression

Input:

```
x3blah0blah4blahblah48blah0
```

Expected output:

```
x003blah000blah004blahblah048blah0
```

I want to pad all digits to 3 digits excluding the last zero digit.
So far, I have:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)/00\1/g'
```

However, this would pad it to 4 if there are 2 digits. I also do not know how to exclude the last zero.

Comment: Do you want to avoid padding that last zero because it's last or because it's zero? i.e. if the last digit was 1 should that be skipped too, or padded to 001?

Comment: Each line has a zero at the end. There are no other nonzero digits that are last.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/\d++(?!$)/sprintf"%03d",$&/ge'
```

Would pad with zeros to a length of 3 the sequences of decimal digits that are not found at the end of the line.

If the string is in a shell variable and that shell is zsh:

```
set -o extendedglob
new_string=${string//(#m)<->[^0-9]/${(l[4][0])MATCH}}
```

To 0-pad (and truncate) to a length a 3 the sequences of digits that are followed by a non-digit.